# Count posts by values from Advanced Custom Field (wordpress)

Tags: php, count, wordpress, posts

I'm trying to count the posts that have the same values checked in a checkbox from the ACF module.

I have a code working for radio buttons, but it does not work on a checkbox where multiple choices are available:

My code so far:

```
    function get_post_count_by_meta( $meta_key, $meta_value, $post_type) {


    $args = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'numberposts'   => -1,          
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
        );

        if ( $meta_key && $meta_value ) {
                if ( is_array($meta_value) ) {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => $meta_key,
                'value' => $meta_value, 
                'compare' => 'LIKE');
        }

        else {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array('key' => $meta_key, 'value' => $meta_value);
        }   
    }

        $posts = get_posts($args);

        $count = count($posts);


    return $count; 

}
 $post_count = get_post_count_by_meta('test_field', 'Value 1', 'any');
echo $post_count;
```

This always responses 0 when the field is a checkbox. There must be something wrong with the $args query. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `numberposts` parameter should be `posts_per_page` ([see docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters))